# Signed App cant install on low end tablet

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, google-places-api, self-signed

Hi guys, I know most of people faced the problem same like me.
But I still cant solve this problems.
I had build android app and this app is using Google Map API and Google Places API.
I had signed my apk file using Eclipse wizard, but when I transfer it to my tab (taiwan product) using SD Card  it said "application not installed". I never installed this app with debug key before. All others Google Map apps I downloaded from Play store can use well in this tab.
I set min android version is 2.2 and highest is 4.0.3. My tab running on 4.0.3.
I also tried to install this app to other brands low end tablet, and it was successful.
But in my tablet, it failed.
Anybody have idea why I can't install this signed apk file? I had tried so much to solve this.
thanks..

Comment: logcat of installation attempt ? try to install via adb and post the result output?

Answer (score 0):

There comes a time in every Android user's life where you want to install an app not found in the Android Market. If it's your first time, you're greeted with, "For security, your phone is set to block installation of applications not obtained from the Android Market" message as you try to install. But how do we get there?

To allow app installs from non-Market apps, tap the menu button on your home screen, then choose Settings >> Applications >> Unknown sources.

Who are these "Unknown sources," and what do they want? Simply put, it's anything other than the Android Market. Could be an app sent by e-mail. Or downloaded from a website.

If you're worried about the security implications of allowing unknown sources, there's an easy fix -- install the app from outside the Android Market, and then hit the checkbox again to turn them back off.

[source](http://www.androidcentral.com/allow-app-installs-unknown-sources).